# gtksourceview keyword escaping

Tags: regex, escaping, gedit, gtksourceview

In my language a keyword is the literal `#list-empty?` so I would like to match against this. I am using gtksourceview to provide syntax highlighting, and using the following definition

`<keyword>list-empty?</keyword>`

However, that matches `list-empt` and `list-empty` (but not the literal `list-empty?`). Which to me would indicate gktsourceview treats what's in `<keyword>` as a regular expression. So I would like to escape the `?` and match it literally. However something like: `<keyword>list-empty\?<keyword>` doesn't work at all.

https://github.com/espringe/wisp/blob/bf1aed13/resources/wisp.lang#L67

So how do i escape the `?` and match against it

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you attempting to match the literal `list-empty?` within the xml file?

Comment: The literal `list-empty?` should get matched and highlighted as a language keyword. Everything else in that file works perfectly

Comment: We don't know how 'your' language works.  What do the `<keyword>` blocks mean, how are they interpreted?

Comment: This is inside gtksourceview language definition: http://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-tutorial.html which I'm using to provide syntax-highlighting for my language. As such, the question is pretty specific to gtksourceview, rather than a general regex question

Comment: So you want to highlight list-empty if it is present in the keyword tag?

Comment: No. The keyword tag is part of gtksourceview language definitions

Comment: @Heptic Thanks for the link.  According to that documentation, every `<keyword>` is a regular expression, so what does `list-emtpy\?` match?  If that isn't working, maybe try `list-empty[\?]{1}` to see if it would interpret that correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(`list-empty\?` and `list-empty[\?]{1}` and `list\-empty[\?]{1}` all don't match `list-empty?`. No idea why, because ? is working as a an optional -- so it does seem to be a regex, but must have some weird escaping ?

Comment: I can't find anything within gtksourceview that would allow the use of `?`.  Depending on how far along you are, maybe don't use `?` and use something like `is-list-empty` instead?

Comment: All the language built-ins get wrapped anyway, so they don't come up often (but when they do, i think it's important they're highlighted). But I'm not very inclined to change my language, so I can have correct syntax highlighting in gedit :D

Comment: Oh!  It was to make the syntax highlighting work in gedit, rather than in the parsing of your language?  Then, I take back my comment to change the language, I thought the language wasn't parsing, not the syntax highlighting of your editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your `keyword` context:

```
<suffix>(?!\w)</suffix>
```

...then go ahead and escape the question mark:

```
<keyword>list-empty\?</keyword>
```

The default suffix is `\b`, on the assumption that every keyword ends with a word character.  Most of yours do, and `(?!\w)` acts just like `\b` in those cases, but it also matches after the question mark while still disallowing the next character to be a word character.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, it actually breaks the matching of all the other keywords. However this probably has given me enough of a clue to figuring it out. So I'll try experiment with a bunch of stuff

Comment: I don't see how that can be.  Are you sure you're doing a negative **lookahead** (`(?!`), not lookbehind (`(?<!`) for a **word character** (lowercase `\w`)?

Comment: hm, wtf. I tried it again, and you're right. I must've made a typo the first time I tried it (which would explain why all the other keywords were breaking)

Answer (score 0):

`?` matches a single character before it

`/list-empty?/` would match both list-empt and list-empty.

You might want to use look ahead:

`<keyword>(?=list\-empty).+` to match the lines which have < keyword > followed by list-empty.

Comment: As I said before list-empty? would match list-empt or list-empty. It only matches if last character y is present or not.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wrote in my initial question. I want to match the *literal* `list-empty?` not `list-empt` and not `list-empty`. As such, I want to escape the ? -- but don't know how to do it in gtksourceview language definitions

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. I am not sure about the gtksourceview language definitions but in regex,  `list\-empty\?` should match the literal `list-empty?`